# Dismiss modal, then immediately push view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

How can I dismiss a modal and then immediately push another view?

I am adding this code in a didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
ChatTableViewController *chatVC = (ChatTableViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"chatVC"];
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:chatVC animated:YES];
}];
```

The modal view dismisses, but nothing happens after. Any ideas?

Comment: Check in [self navigationController] returns nil.

Comment: Not nil: (lldb) po [self navigationController]
<UINavigationController: 0x14548da0>

Comment: Is this piece of code on the modal itself (dismisses itself) or is it on the parent view controller (parent dismisses what it earlier presented)?

Comment: Dismisses itself - which is probably why it doesn't work. Any solutions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't push a view controller into a view dismissed, if it's dismissed it disappears so it's not logical to push another view, cause the parent view controller is deleted. Probably you have this:
- ViewController 1 --> Modal ViewController 2 -->Wanted to dismiss VC2 and push VC3

What you have to do is
- ViewController 1 --> Modal ViewController 2 --> Dismiss VC2 --> Push VC3 on VC1

You can do it with notifications. The most efficient way is to use delegates, create a delegate on VC2 that notifies V1 when it dismisses and then just push VC3.

Answer (score 0):

No, it cant be done that quickly as far as I know, you need to add a delay betwwn the dissmiss and the navigation of another controller, only then will it execute else it would crash an error saying, trying to push a controller while dismissing other

Comment: It absolutely CAN be done that quickly, as the completion block doesn't fire until the initial view has finished making its way on to (or off of) the view stack. The OP was simply attempting to present the new VC on the dismissed modal instead of the presenting parent.

Answer (score 0):

This answer tries to solve the original problem asked above.

A,B,C viewControllers. A is the root VC of a navigationController.

A-> modally_presents -> B-> dismissing_modally_prsented_B_and_automatically_pushing -> C

Note: All presentation and dismissals are done using segues.
I have marked important sequence of actions.

```
class CViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

/************************************************************/

protocol BDelegate: class {
    func BDelegateFunc(someRandomString: String)
}

class BViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: BDelegate?
    var name: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        name = "swappy"
    }

    @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
       // 3 DISMISS using segue
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "unwindToAViewController", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // 4
        print(segue.identifier)
    }

    deinit {
        // 6
        print(String(describing: type(of: self)) + #function)
        delegate?.BDelegateFunc(someRandomString: name!)
    }
}

/************************************************************/

class AViewController: UIViewController, BDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func btnClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        // 1 MODAL 
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "presentBFromA", sender: self)
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "presentBFromA" {
            // 2
            let vc = segue.destination as! BViewController
            vc.delegate = self
        } else if segue.identifier == "showCFromA" {
           // 8 This will finally push C in navigationController
            print(segue.identifier)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func unwindToAViewController(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
       // 5
        print(#function)
    }

    func BDelegateFunc(someRandomString: String) {
        // 7
        print(someRandomString)
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "showCFromA", sender: self)
    }
}
```