# push view controller after dismissing presented view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, pushviewcontroller, presentviewcontroller

I have this navigation stack

**RootVC ---> VC1 --> (presenting)-> ModalVC**

and I have **VC2** (not in navigation stack).

When presenting **ModalVC**, I want to click on button in my ModalVC to dismiss ModalVC, then push **VC2** into the navigation stack after **VC1** at one click. It should look like this:

**RootVC ---> VC1 ---> VC2**

I tried a lot of methods to make it, but pushing event fire only, when I return to my **RootVC**.

I tried to make it with delegates:

In **ModalVC** on click:

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
   if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissAndPush:)]) {
       [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(dismissAndPush:) withObject:VC2];
   }
}];
```

In **VC1**:

```
- (void)dismissAndPush:(UIViewController *)vc {
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];

}
```

Please help to understand this behavior. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Please check the link.I found solution with the help of this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939465/dismiss-modal-then-immediately-push-view-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error has been in other. If Im right understand: some animations before dismissing presented view controller are blocking animations in navigation stack. I solved this problem with 2 ways:

1) deleteting or set right animations before dismissing

2) use setViewControllers in navigation controller (I select it)

```
- (void)dismissAndPush:(UIViewController *)vc {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        NSMutableArray *mutableControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.navigationController.viewControllers];
        NSArray *controllers = [mutableControllers arrayByAddingObject:vc];
        [self.navigationController setViewControllers:controllers animated:NO];
    }];

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24939465/dismiss-modal-then-immediately-push-view-controller 
check this link @RahulMishra

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:):

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view
>   controller it presented.

So, VC1 should be dismissing the ModalVC, try to do this

ModalVC on click:

```
   if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissAndPush:)]) {
       [self.delegate performSelector:@selector(dismissAndPush:) withObject:VC2];
   }
```

In VC1:

```
- (void)dismissAndPush:(UIViewController *)vc {

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:NO];
}];

}
```

Comment: Check if parameter vc is instantiated on dismissAndPush: